# how to use relative path - java

Tags: java, file, gradle, relative-path

I have a git project which contains the following line:

```
public static final String filePath = "C:\\Users\\Dani\\Documents\\projectName\\core\\src\\dogs\\parse\\cards.json";
```

But, in a different computer, the file (which is saved in the project itself) is not at the same root as above..
(In my partner computer, the project is not under Documents, and his user name is not Dani).

I tried to switch  to the following line:

```
  public static final String filePath = "\\projectName\\core\\src\\dogs\\parse\\cards.json";
```

But then, when I run it, exception was rise - file not exist.

Any advices?
Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use like that.

```
  public static final String filePath = "projectName\\core\\src\\dogs\\parse\\cards.json";
```

So it will append the current directory

Comment: still noSuchFileException.. =\

Comment: Try to print the file path once you have created File object

Comment: I am using gradle, and the file is under core lib. and I am running the desktop luncher.. maybe the problem because of it?

Comment: Ya may be i m not sure